# How can I get a smooth plot of a bounded region?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions

From the iterated integrals $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\sqrt{y}}^{1}\int_{x^{3}}^{1}f(x,y),$ we have the region $$\Omega=\{0\le y\le1,\sqrt{y}\le x \le 1,x^{3}\le z \le 1\}.$$

How can I use *Mathematica* to plot $\Omega$?

The following is what I tried.

```
RegionPlot3D[
  x^3 <= z <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && Sqrt[y] <= x <= 1, 
  {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.5]], 
  Mesh -> None]
```

But the edge is bad.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `RegionPlot3D[]`?

Answer (score 5):

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[
   0 <= y <= 1 && Sqrt[y] <= x <= 1 && x^3 <= z <= 1, {x, y, z}];
RegionPlot3D[reg, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Don't forget the PlotPoints!

Answer (score 4):

[`RegionPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot3D.html) will work fine, you just need to give it the proper region and specify the number of `PlotPoints`

```
RegionPlot3D[
 ImplicitRegion[
  x^3 <= z <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && Sqrt[y] <= x <= 1, {x, y, z}], 
 PlotPoints -> 100, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

You can also use `DiscretizeRegion`

```
DiscretizeRegion[
 ImplicitRegion[
  x^3 <= z <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && Sqrt[y] <= x <= 1, {x, y, z}]]
```

[image]

**Edit** ImplicitRegion is also very useful for integration.

```
Integrate[
 Log[ x y], {x, y, z} ∈ 
  ImplicitRegion[
   x^3 <= z <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && Sqrt[y] <= x <= 1, {x, y, z}]]
(* -(5/12) *)
```

Comment: There is something error.Your picture is not the region $\Omega$.

Comment: @AK47 - sorry, I had copied and pasted the region from your original code.

Comment: This might be helpful !